# Cannot Find ASP.NET Identity Tables in Database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I created a database using using EF Code-first Migrations approach. When I ran the application I registered a user and expected that the identity tables be added to the database I created but I couldn't find the tables. I checked my connection string to be sure it is rightly set. Please what could I have missed out? Please help.

**Edit:**
This is the code for the context.

```
public class AppDataContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDataContext()
        : base("AppConnection")
    { }

    public DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ClassInfo> Classes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

    public DbSet<MessageBoard> MessageBoards { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Notification_User> UserNotifications { get; set; }

    public DbSet<NotificationType> NotificationTypes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ParentSubscription> ParentSubscriptions { get; set; }

    public DbSet<PrivateMessage> PrivateMessages { get; set; }

    public DbSet<School> Schools { get; set; }

    public DbSet<SessionPeriod> SessionPeriods { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Setting> Settings { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

    public DbSet<TeacherSchool> TeacherSchools { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Term> Terms { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Work> Works { get; set; }

    public DbSet<WorkType> WorkTypes { get; set; }

    #region Override Methods

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Teachers).WithMany(i => i.Subjects)
        .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("SubjectID")
        .MapRightKey("TeacherID")
        .ToTable("SubjectTeacher"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<ClassInfo>()
            .HasMany(s => s.Subjects).WithMany(c => c.Classes)
            .Map(u => u.MapLeftKey("ClassInfoID").MapRightKey("SubjectID").ToTable("ClassSubject"));

        //modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().MapToStoredProcedures();

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        //modelBuilder.Entity<ClassInfo>()
        //    .Property(f => f.DateAdded)
        //    .HasColumnType("datetime2");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you registered a user ：

1. Refresh your project
2. Show all files

You will find:

[image]

[image]

**Edit：**

IdentityModels.cs:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        //: base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        : base("AppConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}

public class AppDataContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDataContext()
        : base("AppConnection")
    { }


}
```

Web.config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
      <add name="AppConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=SIS_DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I'm not using SQL SERVER EXPRESS Instance. So I don't think I can find it there. I checked though and didn't find it there.

Comment: Your are welcome! So sorry hear that. Which database are you used?

Comment: Sorry what I was meant to say is, I'm not using LocalDB. I am using SQL Server from SQL Mgt Studio.

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication46\WebApplication46\App_Data

Comment: It's an empty folder. I don't think you understand my question. I created my database in SQL Server using Code-First Migrations in Entity Framework. The database exists and works fine. But my issue now is, after registering a user on the application, I couldn't find the aspNet identity tables in the database as expected. But the user was added successfully. Where did it store the user information? I hope you understand my question now?

Comment: Where is the `Context `?

Comment: Maybe your have 2 Contexts,one is your code-first ,the other is ApplicationDbContext.

Comment: No I have just one context in a folder of the web application project.

Comment: Where is `web.config`?
This is mine:

Comment: What would you like to see in the web.config as there's a lot in it?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication47-20160509043622.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication47-20160509043622;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="WebApplication47Context" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=WebApplication47Context-20160509163749;..."
      ... />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Where is your ApplicationDbContext? Your said:"...But the user was added successfully."

Comment: Yes it added successfully. This is my connectionString:      <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppConnection" connectionString="Data Source=kacey-pc;Initial Catalog=SIS_DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Do you have `IdentityModels.cs` file?

Comment: Yes I do. I think I see the problem. The Context name in the file is different from the one in web.config. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111401/discussion-between-hellonewworld-and-kacey-ezerioha).